# How do I avoid deleting text in PHP email form if it's not totally complete

Tags: php, forms, email

I´m new to PHP and I can't figure this out. Below you will see my PHP email form. The problem is that if the user forgets to enter an email and have been written a long message and then hit submit. The page will then reload and a text message comes up and says: You forgot your email. But now the whole message has been deleted from the form and they have to write it all over again. 
How can I echo out that they forgot email or message without reload the page/delete already entered info.

```
<?php

function email() {
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
if ($email)
if ($message)

{
//send email
$to = "xxx@example.com";
$subject = "xxx" ;
$from = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header('Location: sent/');
exit();
}
else  {
echo "You forgot your message.";
} 
else  {
echo "You forgot your email.";
} 
}
?>
```

```
<form class="mail_form" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" method='POST'>
<input class="input_mail" name='email' type='text' placeholder="Your email">
<textarea id="textarea_mail" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" name='message'   cols="30" rows="5"  placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
<input class="send_mail" type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
echo email();
}
?>
```

Comment: Search how to validate forms

Comment: You might want to consider adding some client side validation in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add related `$_POST` value to the field. if it has any it will display the message:

```
<form class="mail_form" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" method='POST'>
    <input class="input_mail" name='email' type='text' placeholder="Your email" value="<?php echo @$_POST['email']; ?>">
    <textarea id="textarea_mail" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" name='message'   cols="30" rows="5"  placeholder="Your message">
        <?php echo @$_POST['message']; ?>
    </textarea>
    <input class="send_mail" type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo email();
    }
?>
```

Comment: @David Of course! you just have to go with the same logic on email input. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use POST to bring everything to the next page. There you use hidden fields and save all availible values in them:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['value']; ?>" />
```

When something is missing, use a submit-button to bring the user back to the last page, and again with POST you bring everything back to the last page.

Answer (score 0):

just echo back the message like:

```
<textarea id="textarea_mail" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" name='message'   
   cols="30" rows="5"  placeholder="Your message">
<?php echo $_REQUEST['message']; ?>
</textarea>
```

but if you get involved a bit of java script or jQuery, you can validate the form before it gets submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Call your $message

```
<textarea id="textarea_mail" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" name='message'   
cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="
<?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } else { echo "Your message";} ?>" >
   </textarea>
```

Don't forget

```
unset($message);


function email() {
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
if ($email)
if ($message)

{
//send email
$to = "xxx@example.com";
$subject = "xxx" ;
$from = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
header('Location: sent/');
exit();
 unset($message);
 unset($mail);
}
else  {
echo "You forgot your message.";
} 
else  {
echo "You forgot your email.";
} 
}
?>
```

When the mail is send

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I wrote I'm new to PHP. But the last thing you wrote: unset($message);
Is that for security? And where to I add that function? Sorry for the rookie questions! :)

Comment: When the mail is sent, it is better to empty the variable. The form will be empty again.

I'll edit my post so you understand where to put.